# Help needed. format turned colored and with bubbles when I hit a question

Tags: support, design

A nonsense format comes up when I hit on the list  of Physics a question to look at it. Colors and bubbles and distracting fuss. Help please. It happened after I rejected and edit by xray0, but it could be a coinidence. ( for many of the corrections I do not see a difference, for some there is grammar capitals or something)

Comment: Alternatively, you could just appreciate comic sans :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry, it''s just an April Fools Day gimmick. You can toggle it off & on with the Clock icon in tbe top bar.

The Clock icon is supposed to disable / enable it on all pages, but it's slightly buggy, and the devs are working on it. In the mean time, if you use the mobile view you'll see a boring normal display. (The "mobile" button is at the bottom of every page).

Also see [How to disable "time travel" entirely?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325996/how-to-disable-time-travel-entirely)

**Update**
The bug is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for the comments. The format returned to normal when clicking on the  clock image on the top line. It is on the right side of the top line.